# iPhone problem saving files with file sharing

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager, file-sharing, ringtone

I have an app that allows the user to click a button to save a ringtone to the documents directory. I have the iPad version working appropriately, however, using the same method for the iPhone doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code I'm using to save:

```
- (IBAction) saveFile:(id)sender {
    // Get the path to the Documents Directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Detect which button was double tapped and set up the file to save
    NSString *filePath;
    NSString *fileName;
    if (sender == downloadRingtone1){
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RingtoneTest" ofType:@"m4r"];
            fileName = @"RingtoneTest.m4r";
    } else if (sender == downloadRingtone2){
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RingtoneTest2" ofType:@"m4r"];
            fileName = @"RingtoneTest2.m4r";

    NSString *m4rPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Detect if the file already exists
    BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:m4rPath];

    if (fileExists) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File Already Saved" message:@"The selected file already exists. Sync to iTunes to finish loading the file." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
    } else {        
            // Save the file        
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:m4rPath error:nil];

            // Notify of the save
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File Saved" message:@"You must sync your device to iTunes to finish loading. For complete instructions, visit the \"Download Instructions\" page." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
    }
}
```

I know its a problem with the file manager. As posted, it always goes into the if statement as if the file exists (which it doesn't). When I comment the if statement out to force it to save, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong? Is there something different you have to do with the iPhone? Also, I don't think its a problem, but I am testing on an iPod touch (it is updated to the latest iOS 4.2.1. I don't have access to an iPhone. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is correct. In case someone is having the same problem, make sure you connect your buttons to the right outlets in Interface Builder.